# ng-options not updated from function callback as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

my js code "ng-option" would not be updated from a function callback.

I tried to remove $watch, options in "ng-option" would show as expected.

And I tried to print console log step by step. Logs in callback for query will be printed, but which in callback for list will not be printed. 
I can see correct output from chrome Network, but not populated in 'select' element.

Is it caused by the js plug-in tm.pagination?

```html
<body>
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>dataSet：</label>
                    <select ng-model="data_set" ng-options="option for option in dataSetList"/>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%"><button ng-click="queryData()" class="btn btn-primary" width="120px;">View</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div >
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in resultset">
                <td>{{item.image_id}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <tm-pagination conf="paginationConf"></tm-pagination>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['tm.pagination']);
    app.service('myService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            query: function (reqData, callBack) {
                SomeService.fun1(reqData, function (error, response) {
                    console.log("it is printed!")
                    if (error == 0) {
                        callBack(response);
                    }
                });
            },
            list: function (reqData, callBack) {
                console.log("it is printed")
                SomeService.fun2(reqData, function (error, response) {
                    console.log("ISSUE: it is not printed!")
                    if (error == 0){
                        callBack(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

    app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myService', function ($scope, myService) {
        var getData = function () {
            var reqData = {
                // request
            }

            var successCb = function (response) {
                $scope.paginationConf.totalItems = response.result.totalcount;
                // other response
                $scope.$apply();
            }
            myService.query(reqData, successCb);
        };

        $scope.paginationConf = {
            currentPage: 1,
            itemsPerPage: 10
        };

        $scope.queryData = function () {
            getData();
        };

        var queryDims = function () {
            var reqData = {
            }
            var successCb = function (response) {
                // ISSUE: it will not come to this block
                $scope.dataSetList = response.result.data_set;
                $scope.$apply();
            }
            myService.list(reqData, successCb);
        };

        $scope.listDims = function () {
            queryDims();
        };

        $scope.listDims();

        $scope.$watch('paginationConf.currentPage + paginationConf.itemsPerPage', getData);
    }]);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: there is an error in your code.  **Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined**

Comment: it's just code sample, not whole code. it will not run successfully.

Comment: i mean atleast give us some working fiddle or snippet